# Compilação de código

Tags: c, c++

Galera me ajudem, não consigo compilar este código: Até inicia a tela de comandos mais nao executa

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
  int x,y,z;
  int a=0;
  for (x=0;x<=1;x=x+1)
    for(y=x;y<=1;y=y+1)
     for(z=y;z<=2;z=z+1)
       a=a+1;
printf("%d",a);
}
```

Comment: aqui compilou, o resultado foi 7, qual erro está dando?

Comment: Como você conseguiu compilar? no meu note não foi. (Windows)

Comment: Só copiei e colei no Dev C++ e compilei com F11. Está com Windows?

Comment: Qual  IDE você esta usando?

Comment: Pode explicar o que é IDE?

Comment: Por exemplo: nem este também consigo compilar   #include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
 int x;
int soma=0;
int k =1;
while (k<=15)
{
scanf("%d", &x);
soma = soma + x;
k = k + 1;
}
}

Comment: Veja funcionando e de forma mais organizada para facilitar a leitura: http://ideone.com/NrJirM. Vou repetir para você não insistir em material que ensina fazer códigos ruins. Se está dando erro de compilar, poste ele. Dê detalhes para podermos ajudar.

Comment: @user32333 Sobre IDE eu uso o CodeBlocks, o amigo acima  usou o  Dev C++ , Esse nome vem do inglês IDE(Integrated Development Environment) .Numa tradução tosca seria: Ambiente de desenvolvimento Integrado.A IDE  tem muitas funcionalidades que auxiliam no desenvolvimento de programas, mas,  a grosso modo, basicamente possuem um compilador e uma interface gráfica!!

Comment: Que compilador você está usando?

Comment: @user32333 Sintaticamente o código está correto. Para saber porque não está compilando, as informações que os amigos acima solicitaram são necessárias. Qual o seu sistema operacional? Qual a sua IDE? Qual o seu compilador? Qual o erro apontado?

Answer (score 1):

System pause é um comando DOS da linguagem c.E serve para utilizar os comandos do DOS. O comando "pause" serve pra pausar o programa e não deixar que ele feche rapidamente. E não pode se esquecer de adicionar include stdlib.h para usá-la.

Answer (score 0):

Não há erros de sintaxe no código. O código C é legítimo, compila e executa. O código executa e escreve um inteiro na tela o número 7. Talvez o problema esteja em alguns detalhes periféricos. Você pode tentar exibir algumas linhas em branco antes e depois do número para que ele fique mas claro na tela:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int x, y, z;
        int a = 0;
        for(x = 0; x <= 1; x = x + 1)
                for(y = x; y <= 1; y = y + 1)
                        for(z = y; z <= 2; z = z + 1)
                                a = a + 1;
printf("\n\n %d \n\n", a);
}
```

Em alguns ambientes pode ser interessante você adicionar `system("pause");` antes de fechar as chaves da `main`, para que dessa forma a janela do `prompt` não se feche sozinho:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int x, y, z;
        int a = 0;
        for(x = 0; x <= 1; x = x + 1)
                for(y = x; y <= 1; y = y + 1)
                        for(z = y; z <= 2; z = z + 1)
                                a = a + 1;
printf("\n\n %d \n\n", a);
system("pause");
}
```

É importante verificar se no momento em que você compila o código não existe nenhuma janela de execução já aberta. Caso exista feche-á antes de compilar o seu código.